# How to send value from Radiobutton UWP

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uwp

Hello so i'm creating this app in UWP using visual studio 2015. I have done 2 radio buttons where you can choose modes on the level, like EASY and MEDIUM. But i cant get it to work properly. So what i want to do is that you can choose one of this buttons and then i want to send the value to my code so it can pick out the right settings. This is my code. XAML:

```
<RadioButton
             Grid.Column="0"
             x:Name="rdiEasy"
             Content="Easy"
             GroupName="mode"
             IsChecked="{x:Null}"                   
             />
<RadioButton
             Grid.Column="1"
             x:Name="rdiMedium"
             Content="Medium"
             GroupName="mode"
             IsChecked="{x:Null}"
             />
```

And here is where i try to send the code, i think its here the problem is.

```
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    Mode mode;

    if (rdiEasy.IsChecked == true)
    {
        mode = Mode.EASY;
    }
    else if (rdiMedium.IsChecked == true)
    {
        mode = Mode.MEDIUM;             

        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Playing), mode);    
    }
```

Here is where i receive the code

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    var mode = e.Parameter;

    if ((Mode)mode == Mode.EASY)
        lstQuestion = db.getEasyMode().OrderBy(s => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();

    else if ((Mode)mode == Mode.MEDIUM)
        lstQuestion = db.getMediumMode().OrderBy(s => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
```

And this is my Class

```
public enum Mode { 
    EASY,
    MEDIUM
}
```

Comment: on Navigated to, UI is still not rendered. Change this to OnLoaded and you should be able to get it working.

Comment: You have put your `Frame.Navigate(typeof(Playing), mode);` inside your `else if` statement. That way you only go to the next page when Medium is selected. You should put navigation outside the else if.